# Overflow hidden for CircleAvatar wiget (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I need to put icon into CircleAvatar Widget to allow user upload his image.

Something like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
child: CircleAvatar(
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        height: 33,
        child: Container(
          height: 20,
          width: 30,
          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .74),
          child: Center(
            child:
                Icon(Icons.photo_camera, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
  radius: 68.0,
  backgroundImage:
      NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/300'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
)
```

But I have this result:

[image]

Internal box with camera icon overflow from parent widget (CircleAvatar);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want can be simply done with - `ClipOval`

Your Code:

```
body: Center(
        child: CircleAvatar(
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/300'),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  height: 33,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){
                      print('upload Clicked');
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 30,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .74),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Icon(Icons.photo_camera, color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          radius: 68.0,
          // backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/300'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Custom Clipper to give the circular bottom to your widget.

You need to use the `ClipPath widget` for it, pass your widget in your case `Container` containing your camera icon.

and in `clipper` pass your `CustomClipper`.

**ClipPath**

```dart
    return ClipPath(
      child: your_widget,
      clipper: BottomWaveClipper(),
    );
```

**CustomCliper**

```dart
    class BottomCircleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
      @override
      Path getClip(Size size) {
        //your path to draw circle
      }

      @override
      bool shouldReclip(TriangleClipper oldClipper) => false;
    }
```

Here are some links that will help you.

https://iirokrankka.com/2017/09/04/clipping-widgets-with-bezier-curves-in-flutter/

https://medium.com/flutter-community/clipping-in-flutter-e9eaa6b1721a